# lines inside table disappears when zooming in/out

Tags: tables, color, rendering

When I zoom in/out on the tables, the separator lines appear and disappear according to the level of zoom. I Have tried using several pdf viewer, but it doesn't solve the problem. If I remove the colors from my table, this is no longer a problem. Why is this happening, and can someone help me solve the problem?

I am using these color packages, and the code can be seen below.

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}


\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Eksempler på søkeord og resultater}
\label{tabell_sokeord}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|r|l}
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Søkeord} & \textbf{Søkemotor} & \textbf{Antall resultater} & \textbf{Benyttet kilde} \\[6pt]  \hline 
\rowcolor[HTML]{F0F0F0} 4D & Google Scholar & 2 490 000 &  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{E2E2E2}4D BIM & Google Scholar & 29 200 &  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{F0F0F0} "4D BIM" & Google Scholar & 2 780 &  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{E2E2E2}"4D BIM"\hspace{2pt}Modeling & Google Scholar & 2 710 &  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{F0F0F0}"4D BIM"\hspace{2pt}Modeling & Google Scholar & 1 060 & \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{F0F0F0}(senere enn år 2016) & &&  \\
 \rowcolor[HTML]{E2E2E2}"4D BIM Modeling" & Google Scholar & 17 & Automated Mining of Construction Schedules \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{E2E2E2}(senere enn år 2016) & && for Easy and Quick Assembly of 4D BIM \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{E2E2E2} & & & Simulations\citep{torres-calderon_automated_2019}\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{F0F0F0}\textquotedbl4D BIM\textquotedbl\hspace{1pt}\&\hspace{1pt}\textquotedbl Safety planning\textquotedbl& Google Scholar & 335 & 4D-BIM for Construction Safety Planning \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{F0F0F0} &&& \citep{sulankivi_4d-bim_2010}
\end{tabular}% 
}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\end{table}
```

[image: not all of the lines are showing]

[image: code]

Comment: it's a feature of the way colortbl works and can't always be avoided (I would say it's best to avoid rules with coloured tables. But you are applying `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` it is _never_  good to scale tables in this way as it produces inconsistent font and rule sizes, and is likely to make the issue worse here so I would start by removing that, Also please provide the example in a form that people can run to see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0) solves your problem.

This package creates PGF/Tikz nodes corresponding to the position of the cells in the tabular and writes this information in the `.aux` file. In the second compilation, all the colored panels are drawn *before* all the rules. Thus, the PDF viewers are not disturbed (in a PDF created by `colortbl`, an horizontal rule is drawn before the following colored rectangle corresponding to a row, and during the rasterisation process, many viewers give priority to the colored rectangle drawn after, thus erasing the horizontal rule (depending of the zoom level)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Eksempler på søkeord og resultater}
\label{tabell_sokeord}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{L|L|R|L}[
code-before = \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}{1}
              \rowcolor[HTML]{F0F0F0}{2,4,6,7,11,12}
              \rowcolor[HTML]{E2E2E2}{3,5,8-10}
]
\textbf{Søkeord} & \textbf{Søkemotor} & \textbf{Antall resultater} & \textbf{Benyttet kilde} \\[6pt]  \hline 
 4D & Google Scholar & 2 490 000 &  \\
4D BIM & Google Scholar & 29 200 &  \\
 "4D BIM" & Google Scholar & 2 780 &  \\
"4D BIM"\hspace{2pt}Modeling & Google Scholar & 2 710 &  \\
"4D BIM"\hspace{2pt}Modeling & Google Scholar & 1 060 & \\
(senere enn år 2016) & &&  \\
"4D BIM Modeling" & Google Scholar & 17 & Automated Mining of Construction Schedules \\
(senere enn år 2016) & && for Easy and Quick Assembly of 4D BIM \\
 & & & Simulations\\
\textquotedbl4D BIM\textquotedbl\hspace{1pt}\&\hspace{1pt}\textquotedbl Safety planning\textquotedbl& Google Scholar & 335 & 4D-BIM for Construction Safety Planning \\
 &&& 
\end{NiceTabular}% 
}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

You need to compile twice.

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Wow, this seems really nice!
I pastet the code and compiled two times, but somehow it didn't work.
It does not show in the pdf at all..

I got an error in my code saying: 
"Latex error: NiceTabular environment undefined..."

Comment: @Mats: You need the latest version of `nicematrix` (4.1). This version uses recent features of `expl3` which is now a part of the LaTeX kernel. That means that you should update thoroughly your TeX installation.

Comment: hmm. We are currently using Overleaf. Do you know if it is possible to upload this package into our overleaf project?

Comment: On CTAN, the last version of `nicematrix` is 4.1. I have just tried on Overleaf and it doesn't work because Overleaf is still using TeXLive 2019 (and not TeXLive 2020). However, I can send you a slight modification of the file `nicematrix.sty` and it works. I have just tried. If you are interessed, send me an email: fpantigny@wanadoo.fr.

Comment: This would be really nice, i will email you!

Comment: In this answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `l|l|r|l` instead of `L|L|R|L` in the preamble of `{NiceTabular}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).